# Testcafe: How to ignore the failed xhr requests on the page that we are trying to test

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

While running testcafe, I could see an xhr request failing in the background and may be that is why I could not see the UI elements of the page getting loaded. I could see only one element loaded.

If I try to access the same webpage without testcafe, I could see the page elements loading normal although the xhr request is still failing in the background.

Could this failing xhr request be a reason for the page not showing all the UI elements when I do it through testcafe?

Is there a way to ignore some xhr requests like this in testcafe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mock any request you can use [RequestMock](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402667/reference/test-api/requestmock). For example:

```js
const mock = RequestMock()
    .onRequestTo('http://xhr-request/')
    .respond('Mocked respond');
```

However, it may not resolve the problem. If it doesn't help, please, share a minimal working example with [this template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A%20bug&template=bug_report.yaml) following [this instruction](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue).

Comment: thank you @Aleksey, it solved the problem. Mocked the failing request, works like a charm now - : )